# How to create OAuthParameters from access token for Google Contacts API

Tags: java, google-oauth, gdata-api, google-data-api, google-oauth-java-client

I have implemented my OAuth2 client myself. It works, I have *client id*, *client secret* and *access token*. I also have *refresh token* an can receive new access tokens from it.

But how to use these Strings with Google API for Java (Contacts API)?

I have created `ContactsService service = new ContactsService("<var>test</var>");`

It seams I have to provide OAuthParameters to service.`setOAuthCredentials()`, but OAuthCredentials has no field for access token or refresh token. There is only `setOAuthToken()` and `setOAuthTokenSecret()`. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was not to use `setOAuthCredentials()`. Instead:

```
service.setPrivateHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
```